# What is `response.send` (from README.md of redux-thunk)?

Tags: redux-thunk

Find it in [Composition section](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition)

Where it come from?

---

```
// This is very useful for server side rendering, because I can wait
// until data is available, then synchronously render the app.

store.dispatch(
  makeSandwichesForEverybody()
).then(() =>
  response.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MyApp store={store} />))
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it comes from Javascript XMLHttpRequest

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send